# How can I DRY up this Rails API create response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

The below code fields very wordy to me - is there a way to DRY this up?

```
    if @job.save
         respond_to do |format|
            format.xml {
               render xml: {error: "Job created successfully."}, status: 200
            }
           format.json {
               render json: {error: "Job created successfully."}, status: 200
            }
         end
      else
         respond_to do |format|
            format.xml {
               render xml: {error: @job.errors}, status: 422
            }
           format.json {
               render json: {error: @job.errors}, status: 422
            }
         end
      end
```

Comment: I think the only DRYing would be avoiding writing `respond_to do |format|` two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`respond_to` and `respond_with`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html):

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :xml, :json

  def create
    if @job.save
      respond_with {error: "Job created successfully."}, status: 200
    else
      respond_with {error: @job.errors}, status: 422
    end
  end
end
```